# MySQL string comparison without operator - inconsistency on the same server?

Tags: mysql

I found what is to me a really weird phenomenon. In my MySQL server which is version 5.0.92, I use a query as follows:

```
SELECT IF(thumb, thumb, image) AS thumb FROM blog WHERE id = 200;
```

Because I want to get the thumb value if it is not empty, otherwise the image value. Now in one database on this server, this works perfectly fine, just the way I want it to. But on another database on the exact same server, `thumb` *always* evaluates to false, even it is not empty, and the value for `image` is always selected.

I know that I can use `thumb != ''` and that does work on both databases but please someone tell me how this happened? Is this some kind of database-specific setting?

Comment: check the db default, if thumb is empty is it empty string or null?

Comment: Neither thumb nor image are set to be able to be NULL, so NULL shouldn't come up as a problem at all.
I am talking about whether the string has a length of at least 1.
On the problematic database, if thumb has a value of thumb.jpg, IF(thumb, thumb, image) still evaluates to false and the value of image is selected, which would be the problem and inconsistency, because it works as I want it to on the other database.

Comment: try select `if("text here", 'yes', 'no')`, what is the output, it should be false

Comment: In that case, "text here" seems to evaluate to false on both databases, and 'no' is returned always.

Answer (score 0):

If `thumb` is string column then you should be using query something like:

```
SELECT IF(thumb IS NOT NULL AND thumb != '', thumb, image) AS thumb FROM blog WHERE id = 200;
```

Also check for the `CHARACTER SET` of both databases as string comparison depends on character set.

```
SHOW CREATE DATABASE db_name;
```

[Database Character Set and Collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-database.html)

Comment: I'm sorry, but this wasn't the case. The columns all use the exact same character set, neither of them can be null, and `SHOW CREATE DATABASE db_name;` shows the exact same thing for both of the databases (except the names the databases of course)

Comment: there could be a problem with `NULL` values or may be MySQL compiled from different sources.

Comment: The columns are set so that they cannot be `NULL`. And we're talking about the same MySQL server, but different databases.

Comment: I hope your two tables are exactly identical having exact same data. that's weird there must be some database level setting otherwise. check SELECT @@SESSION.sql_mode;

Comment: They do not have identical data, but the relevant part is the same: under `thumb` the cell contains a non-empty string. I'll probably show some screenshots too, for easier visualization.
`SELECT @@SESSION.sql_mode;` selects an empty string for both databases.